# ngrx store select always returning undefined

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

Trying to use ngrx in a project and stuck as store.select always returning undefined. The action seems to be dispatched and I can see the payload has the data. I can see the data even in the Redux DevTools but somehow it never reaches to the controller. I have made a test github repo as there will be too much code to paste here. I have tried many combinations finally given up so really appreciate any help of what i'm doing wrong. I hope someone can help me.

https://github.com/lawphotog/simplest_ngrx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to return `store.photos`, but it doesn't look like your store has a `photos` entry. You set up your store with `StoreModule.forRoot({reducer})`. And your reducer looks like this

```
case fromPhotos.PhotosActionTypes.LOAD_PHOTOS_SUCCESS: 
  console.log('payload: ' + JSON.stringify(action.payload))
  return action.payload;
default:
  return state;
```

And `action.payload` is an array. So, after you've done `fromPhotos.PhotosActionTypes.LOAD_PHOTOS_SUCCESS`, your store looks like (I think) :

```
{
  reducer: []
}
```

You're trying to get `store.photos` from the store, which doesn't exist. You should try `store.reducer` and see what happens.

This all being said, to my eyes, you have a really wonky Store setup. I'd recommend heading over to NGRX and looking through their [example app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app) / docs (note, they're in the process of updating their docs for NGRX v5 (which hasn't been released yet), so the docs aren't 100% current). For example, the pattern I've usually seen for stores (not that I'm an expert) is something like

```
{
  photosReducer: {
    photos: []
  }
}
```

Then you could select photos with `store.select(store => store.photosReducer.photos`. Or, the method I use `store.select('photosReducer', 'photos')`. Also (and maybe this is just because you're experimenting) but your `fromPhotos.PhotosActionTypes.LOAD_PHOTOS_SUCCESS` action should merge its results into the store (currently, your replacing the entire store with the results). Something like

```
case fromPhotos.PhotosActionTypes.LOAD_PHOTOS_SUCCESS: 
  console.log('payload: ' + JSON.stringify(action.payload))
  return { 
    ...state,
    photos: action.payload;
  }
default:
  return state;
```

Comment: Also, [ultimate angular](https://platform.ultimateangular.com/p/ngrx-store-effects) recently released a free ngrx course that might be helpful:

Comment: If `store.select(store => store.reducer)` doesn't work, you could try simply `console.log(store.select(store => store))` to see what the store object looks like.

Comment: thanks for your help @John. I haven't fully solved my problem but you gave me a big help. I can now see the values in store.select(store => store) but trying to figure out how to get it out. I was watching one NGRX course from Pluralsight but Todd Motto's course looks great.

Comment: Hi @John. it is working fully now. made a few changes in the above repo. it took me ages to realise that the name of the Reducer in the AppState (photosReducer for instance) is the one that I need to put in StoreModule.forRoot({photosReducer}). thanks for your help again. Will watch that Todd Motto's course now.